# How can I pass req to Mongoose model constructor?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am trying to set some default values for a document by fetching them from the settings of the current user, which is available in the req.user object in my express middleware.

I know that it's possible to pass the req object to middleware, but is it possible to pass it to the Schema default functions? Something like:

```
var Comment = new Schema({
  mood:{ type: String, default: function(req) {
    return (req.user.defaults.mood);
  }},
  content: String
});
```

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to do exactly what you're asking for (probably not), but one way would be to create a custom save-method which takes a req-object and checks if values are missing before saving. See [the guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods).

Comment: Yeah, that _could_ work, but I'm hoping for a solution that would allow me to leverage the already-existing default options I have declared in my Schema definition. I was thinking that maybe I can create a custom Model constructor, so that I can pass in the req object.